I can't reach my User Context Login function
i'm new in React and i'm following the this Teddy Smith tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3o0st1WdlsU) to develop a Login system.
I'm facing this anoying situation that follows:
import { createContext, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { UserProfile } from "../Models/User";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { loginAPI } from "../Services/AuthService";
import { toast } from "react-toastify";
import React from "react";
import axios from "axios";

type UserContextType = {  
    user: UserProfile | null;
    token: string | null;
    loginUser: (username: string, password: string) => void;
};

type Props = { children: React.ReactNode };

const UserContext = createContext<UserContextType>({} as UserContextType);

export const UserProvider = ({ children }: Props) => {
    const navigate = useNavigate();
    const [token, setToken] = useState<string | null>(null);
    const [user, setUser] = useState<UserProfile | null>(null);
    const [isReady, setIsReady] = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {
        const user = localStorage.getItem("user");
        const token = localStorage.getItem("token");
        if (user && token) {
            setUser(JSON.parse(user));
            setToken(token);
            axios.defaults.headers.common["Authorization"] = "Bearer " + token;
        }
        setIsReady(true);
    }, []);

    // the function I want to Reach!!!!!!
    const loginUser = async (username: string, password: string) => {
        await loginAPI(username, password)
        .then((res) => {
            if (res) {
                localStorage.setItem("token", res?.data.token);
                const userObj = {
                    userName: res?.data.userName,
                    email: res?.data.email,
                };
                localStorage.setItem("user", JSON.stringify(userObj));
                setToken(res?.data.token!);
                setUser(userObj!);
                toast.success("Login Success!");
                navigate("/search");
            }
        })
        .catch((e) => toast.warning("Server error occured"));
    };



    return (
        <UserContext.Provider
            value={{ loginUser, user, token }}
        >
        {isReady ? children : null}
    </UserContext.Provider>
    );
};

export const useAuth = () => React.useContext(UserContext);

This code above is my login context file, the same code of Teddy's tutorial, and I'm trying to reach that loginUser function by this call on the code bellow, just like the tutorial as well:
import React from "react";
import * as Yup from "yup";
import { yupResolver } from "@hookform/resolvers/yup";
import { useAuth } from "../../Context/UseAuth";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";

type Props = {};

type LoginFormsInputs = {
 userName: string;
 password: string;
};

const validation = Yup.object().shape({
 userName: Yup.string().required("Username is required"),
 password: Yup.string().required("Password is required"),
});

// the loginUser function call reach this point instead of the function on the Context file
const LoginPage = (props: Props) => {
 const { loginUser } = useAuth();
 const {
   register,
   handleSubmit,
   formState: { errors },
 } = useForm<LoginFormsInputs>({ resolver: yupResolver(validation) });

 const handleLogin = (form: LoginFormsInputs) => {
     //The point I am calling the function!!!! 
     loginUser(form.userName, form.password);
 };
 return (
   <section className="bg-gray-50 dark:bg-gray-900">
     <div className="flex flex-col items-center justify-center px-6 py-8 mx-auto md:h-screen lg:py-0">
       <div className="w-full bg-white rounded-lg shadow dark:border md:mb-20 sm:max-w-md xl:p-0 dark:bg-gray-800 dark:border-gray-700">
         <div className="p-6 space-y-4 md:space-y-6 sm:p-8">
           <h1 className="text-xl font-bold leading-tight tracking-tight text-gray-900 md:text-2xl dark:text-white">
             Sign in to your account
           </h1>
           <form
             className="space-y-4 md:space-y-6"
             onSubmit={handleSubmit(handleLogin)}
           >
             <div>
               <label
                 htmlFor="email"
                 className="block mb-2 text-sm font-medium text-gray-900 dark:text-white"
               >
                 Username
               </label>
               <input
                 type="text"
                 id="username"
                 className="bg-gray-50 border border-gray-300 text-gray-900 sm:text-sm rounded-lg focus:ring-primary-600 focus:border-primary-600 block w-full p-2.5 dark:bg-gray-700 dark:border-gray-600 dark:placeholder-gray-400 dark:text-white dark:focus:ring-blue-500 dark:focus:border-blue-500"
                 placeholder="Username"
                 {...register("userName")}
               />
               {errors.userName ? (
                 <p className="text-white">{errors.userName.message}</p>
               ) : (
                 ""
               )}
             </div>
             <div>
               <label
                 htmlFor="password"
                 className="block mb-2 text-sm font-medium text-gray-900 dark:text-white"
               >
                 Password
               </label>
               <input
                 type="password"
                 id="password"
                 placeholder="••••••••"
                 className="bg-gray-50 border border-gray-300 text-gray-900 sm:text-sm rounded-lg focus:ring-primary-600 focus:border-primary-600 block w-full p-2.5 dark:bg-gray-700 dark:border-gray-600 dark:placeholder-gray-400 dark:text-white dark:focus:ring-blue-500 dark:focus:border-blue-500"
                 {...register("password")}
               />
               {errors.password ? (
                 <p className="text-white">{errors.password.message}</p>
               ) : (
                 ""
               )}
             </div>
             <div className="flex items-center justify-between">
               <a
                 href="#"
                 className="text-sm text-white font-medium text-primary-600 hover:underline dark:text-primary-500"
               >
                 Forgot password?
               </a>
             </div>
             <button
               type="submit"
               className="w-full text-white bg-lightGreen hover:bg-primary-700 focus:ring-4 focus:outline-none focus:ring-primary-300 font-medium rounded-lg text-sm px-5 py-2.5 text-center dark:bg-primary-600 dark:hover:bg-primary-700 dark:focus:ring-primary-800"
             >
               Sign in
             </button>
             <p className="text-sm font-light text-gray-500 dark:text-gray-400">
               Don’t have an account yet?{" "}
               <a
                 href="#"
                 className="font-medium text-primary-600 hover:underline dark:text-primary-500"
               >
                 Sign up
               </a>
             </p>
           </form>
         </div>
       </div>
     </div>
   </section>
 );
};

export default LoginPage;


By debug, on browser, when the loginUser function is called in the login page, the code don't reach the function loginUser on the context, de execution goes to the beggining of the Login Page file (const LoginPage = (props: Props) => {...)
The thing is I downloaded the entire project from the tutorial and in this project this same code works as expected, and I spent hours wondering why that doesn't work on my project.
The console error is:
LoginPage.tsx:29 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: loginUser is not a function at handleLogin (LoginPage.tsx:29:5)
grateful for any help.
